# How can I copy to folder if exists delete source file do not modify destination?

Tags: windows-7, script

I want to execute a script to compile all pdfs into a single folder.  My target folder may have the file already.  I want to create a script that searches another set of directories for *.pdf and copy them to target, however if the file already exist in the target just delete the source file and leave the target file alone.  Is there a way to efficiently script this?

Comment: Would you be open to using PowerShell?  Though I'm sure it can be done in Batch, I'm also confident someone else here has a better solution in PS.  Since it comes built-in to Windows 7, I highly recommend you try it out.

Comment: That would be fine. That is to say I'm not opposed to it.  I'll do some more googling

Comment: If you already have experience with any of Perl, Python, or Ruby, this is a perfect use case for one of those languages, as they each have a much more robust set of tools for managing files than Batch scripts.

Comment: The simplest solution would be batch or powershell as Iszi suggested, though any scripting language could do this easily (perl, python, ruby as suggested by asfallows, but also autoit).

Comment: Of course, there's always good ol' `C-x M-c M-butterfly`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to do that with [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) and the right combination of arcane flags but I'd recommend some serious testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXIST filename (
del filename
) ELSE (
mv filename targetpath
)
```

I found this example from [this website](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html). You could nest this in a loop which iterates over whatever set of directories you like, passing the filenames into the `IF` one by one.

Comment: Sounds like a `FOR` or `FOR /F` loop may be what's needed here.  Not sure how you'd like to pass the filename between `FOR` and `IF` though.